# Website is showing infinite redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, migration, redirect-loop

I have a redirect issue on the website

```
The dmhdubai.com page isn’t working

dmhdubai.com redirected you too many times.
```

It was run on cloudflare then i changed the nameservers new server and changed back to the original nameservers .

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

@info, it appears your website dmhdubai.com is not stuck in a redirect loop. You'll need to clear your browser cache to remove any past redirects caused by previous directives.

You can check your website's redirect route at [www.wheregoes.com/retracer.php](http://www.wheregoes.com/retracer.php).

Comment: it was a redirect issue in htaccess. the host solved it (not sure how they did)